# Let $f : [a,b] \times [c,d] \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Let $F(t,y) = \int_{a}^{t} f(x,y) dx$ be a function. Show that F is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

> Let $f : [a,b] \times [c,d] \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Let $F(t,y) = \int_{a}^{t} f(x,y) dx$ be a function. Show that F is continuous.

I attempted to prove the above but I am not sure whether this is correct. It goes as follows:

Consider:

For $(t, y), (t_0, y) \in [a,b] \times [c,d]$

\begin{align*}
|F(t, y) - F(t_0, y_0)| & = |\int_{a}^{t} f(x,y) - \int_{a}^{t_0} f(x, y_0)\ dx| \\
& = |\int_{a}^{t_0} f(x,y) dx - \int_{a}^{t_0} f(x,y) dx + \int_{a}^{t} f(x,y) - \int_{a}^{t_0} f(x, y_0)\ dx| \\
& \leq |\int_{a}^{t} f(x,y) dx - \int_{a}^{t_0} f(x,y) dx| + |\int_{a}^{t_0} f(x, y) - f(x, y_0) dx | 
\end{align*}

And we have continuity since we have from FTC that the if f is integrable (which it is since continuity implies integrability) then $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$ is continuous. And the second integral is also continuous since f is continuous on [a,b] x [c,d]. Hence it follows that F is continuous.

Does this hold?

Comment: Quote from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so."

Comment: The argument after "And we have continuity since" does not justify your claim, because here $f$ also depends on $y$.

Comment: @AnneBauval For the first integrand continuous wrt t and we only require that since the y here is the same for both integrals?

Comment: $y$ is not fixed. You must prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, $|\int_{a}^{t} f(x,y) dx - \int_{a}^{t_0} f(x,y) dx|<\epsilon$ for every $(t,y)$ close enough to $(t_0,y_0)$. Don't use the FTC. Simply notice that   $\int_{a}^{t} f(x,y) dx - \int_{a}^{t_0} f(x,y) dx=
\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x,y) dx$   and $f$ is bounded

Comment: Your argument "since $f$ is continuous" for $|\int_{a}^{t_0} f(x, y) - f(x, y_0) dx | $ is not sufficient either. You need to write a detailed proof.

Comment: @AnneBauval that makes sense thanks